# How to center a div tag with multiple images in it?

Tags: html, css, image, center

I know there are conditions for centering a div tag and different conditions for centering an img tag but I am having trouble using them together. Can someone please help me?

A lot of other questions with answers on this site about centering divs and imgs.

```html
</div>
<div id="draginto"></div>
<div id="cards">
    <img src="Assignment10images/d8.gif">
    <img src="Assignment10images/dJ.gif">
    <img src="Assignment10images/dK.gif">
    <img src="Assignment10images/d10.gif">
    <img src="Assignment10images/dQ.gif">
    <img src="Assignment10images/d9.gif">
</div>
```

```css
#cards {
        position: absolute;
}
```

I expect the images to center, but they just stay in the same position.

Comment: Flexbox is your friend. Not really sure exactly what you are trying to achieve but have a look at this in depth tutorial on flexbox and in particular `justify-content` https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You definitely don't want to be using position absolute as it takes the images out of the flow of the document and will affect the way you position other elements on the page.

Comment: A good way to show us want you are trying to achieve might be to draw a quick diagram in paint or some other tool like that because right now the code and explanation you have given us isn't really clear. :)

Comment: For future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Answer (score 0):

position absolute won't do the trick.

Try this:

```
   <div id="cards">
        <img src="Assignment10images/d8.gif">
        <img src="Assignment10images/dJ.gif">
        <img src="Assignment10images/dK.gif">
        <img src="Assignment10images/d10.gif">
        <img src="Assignment10images/dQ.gif">
        <img src="Assignment10images/d9.gif">
  </div>

  #cards img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  }
```

Comment: after that the images are centered, but they are stacked on top of each other. How could I fix that?

Comment: did you removed the "position: absolute" ?

Comment: try this: #cards img {
clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  }

Comment: just tried it, the images still stay in the same position

Comment: Ok, i think theres something more in your code that is changing the behavior of this group of images. I created a playground with the same html/css. heres the link http://codepen.io/CPJ/pen/VJJVBJ

Comment: yes, that is what i see, but I want the images to be side by side

Comment: oh, my bad! add "float:left" to css and it must work. If you need to restrict the width of the space, then you need to add another rule like this: #card { width: 50%}

Comment: i put float: left, but now we are back to where we originally were.

Comment: Must be the width of your images, i just updated the codepen playground. See if is this what you need http://codepen.io/CPJ/pen/VJJVBJ

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you mean but it seems like all you want to do is center the container for the images and let them flow left to right in a grid down the container? In which case it is as simple as this:

Set a width on the cards container and set the margin to auto to center it:

```css
.cards {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="app">
    <div class="cards">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/gawikud/edit?html,css,output

Comment: sorry, that actually isnt what i wanted.

Comment: yeah well like I said and others have said you haven't been specific enough for anyone to help you out here so I just took a best guess sorry

Answer (score 0):

**Use Flexbox or Grid**

```
#cards {
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/